# Desktop notification sounds not working after recent upgrades

Tags: 11.10, sound, upgrade, pidgin, sound-theme

After recent updates, desktop notification sounds stopped working. For example, sounds in pidgin no longer work. But when I go to Pidgin sound preferences and preview the sounds, they work. Also the sound in the applications work fine as usual. Could this be a bug or is there some workaround for this problem?

Comment: Is there any application besides Pidgin in which sounds are not working? If it's just Pidgin whose sounds you're not hearing (but you hear them when you preview them), then uncheck `Tools` > `Mute Sounds` in Pidgin.

Comment: It is already unchecked.

Comment: The problem was that 'Enable sounds' in Tools->Preferences->Sound was set to 'Only when available' and some how my status was set a few days back to away.  Changing 'Enable sounds' to always solved the problem.

Comment: @EliahKagan, Even the Ubuntu login sound I didn't hear. But I now found out that it is an issue with Ubuntu where I have to copy all the sound files from /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo to /usr/share/sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with Pidgin was that 'Enable sounds' in Tools->Preferences->Sound was set to 'Only when available' and some how my status was set a few days back to away.

As for the other desktop notification sounds like the login sound - I found out that it is an issue with Ubuntu where I have to copy all the sound files from `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo` to `/usr/share/sounds`. After doing that, the standard Ubuntu login sound played on login.

Comment: If this resolved your problem, could you please mark it as such by clicking the checkmark to the left of your answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the standard notification sounds, which are set in system settings => sound will not work in Compiz, it seems.  But it's not a sound problem; somehow, the actual event is not being sent.  This is the sound used for errors or warnings.  It includes the visual alerts that can be enabled in system settings => universal access (which has a button that triggers the sound + visual cue).

I found that it works correctly using Metacity, so I entered a bug report to Compiz.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to:

1. Open `dconf-editor`.
2. Navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.sound` and enable `event-sounds`.

Answer (score 1):

using ubuntu 12.04, i installed ubuntu-tweak and on the **Tweaks** tab, enter the **sound** section and then enable **Event sounds** and choose a **Sound theme** (default "ubuntu").

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following startup item to the startup applications.

Step 1: Click on the system menu at the top right of the screen (looks like a wheel)
Step 2: Click on startup applications
Step 3: Click add.
Step 4: Complete with the following:

```
Name: GNOME Login sound
Command: /usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"
Comment: Startup Sound
```

Step 5: Click add.
Step 6: Click close in the bigger box.
Step 7: Log off and log in.

That worked for me.